# Fake column mysql with value

Tags: mysql

Hello guys i would like know if possible add a fake column with a value that it doesn't exist on the database. Example:

table user

```
id_user | name | surname |

1         jhon    Smith
2         Elis    Sun
```

When i'll go to select i would like put a fake column called type_user with the value 1

result

```
id_user | name | surname | type_user /* fake column */
1         jhon   Smith       1
1         Elis   Sun         1
```

Comment: `SELECT *, 1 type_user FROM tablename` -- try it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will just hard-code the column and value:

```
select id_user, name, surname, 1 as type_user
from user
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id_user, name, surname, 1 as type_user FROM ...
```